# aused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to register broad for internet connection and wifi scan results but I am getting this error."caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null". The internet conccection broadcast works but not the of the wifi scan result.
I Appreciate any help.

MainActivity:

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 BroadcastReceiverListener receiver;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiverListener();

 }

 private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

   }

   else if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

   }
  }
 };

 protected void onResume() {

 

  IntentFilter wifi = new IntentFilter();
  wifi.addAction(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
  registerReceiver(receiver, wifi);

  IntentFilter conn = new IntentFilter();
  conn.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
  registerReceiver(receiver, conn);

  super.onResume();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  super.onDestroy();
 }

}
```

Mainfest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bustracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Enable to check if the wifi is available -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BCR"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bcr" >
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: @DavidJhones I added my manifest

Comment: why you have initiate another local receiver object when you have already instance receiver ?

Comment: @DavidJhons I have deleted the object.. please see my updated question

Comment: so didnt you tried Ravi's answer ??

Comment: Yes I tried you can see the change in the question code too.

Comment: so , you still getting the error ??

Comment: The error does not occur at the moment but I am not getting the broadcast of the wifi scan result. The code for that works without the BroadcastReceiver. it functions properly.

Comment: @MrAsker It would be best to not post extraneous code in questions.  For example, you posted your AndroidManifest even though it has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new (local) `BroadcastReceiver` in your `onResume()`

```
BroadcastReceiverListener receiver = new BroadcastReceiverListener();
```

but in your `onPause()` the `receiver` refers to the uninitialized instance variable which is `null`

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver); // receiver is null
```

So, to fix the issue just instantiate the `receiver` once in your `onCreate()` method

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiverListener();
```

Then both `onPause()` and `onResume()` will un/register the same instance.

Comment: Please check my updated question code because I am still not getting the broadcast of the wifi scan result. The internet connectio one works.

Comment: Cover your unregister and register with `try-catch` in case they have already exposed to registration or un-registration.

Answer (score -2):

You should not unregister receiver in **onPause** method. Do it inside **onDestroy**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

When you go to your wifi settings, the **onPause** method of your activity gets called so if you unregister receiver in **onPause**, android system will not be able to notify user about the update thats why it gives IllegalArgumentException.

Do not call **super.onPause()** inside **onDestroy()** method

Comment: There are plenty of cases in SDK samples where they are unregistering the receiver in `onPause()`...

Comment: @Vikalp, I disagree with you, there are cases in which onDestroy() will not be called, hence receiver will not be unregistered causing a memory leak. It is not a good practice to unregister in OnDestroy().