# Unregistering BroadcastReceiver registered in Activity context results in IllegalArgumentException crash

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

The crash is pretty strange one.

In `onStart`, BroadcastReceiver that is stored in the Activity field is registered. In `onStop`, this BroadcastReceiver is unregistered. When BroadcastReceiver was successfully registered, I also set `isRegistered` field to `true`, and before I unregister the receiver, I check this field to see if we need

However, in Crashlytics I see that sometimes this fails, and the whole app crashes with `IllegalArgumentException` with `Receiver not registered` message, which originates from `android.app.LoadedApk#forgetReceiverDispatcher`. Which is pretty strange, considering that I check the flag, right?

After I looked into `ContextImpl` and `LoadedApk` classes which handle registration/unregistration and added some reflection-based diagnostics, it got even more mysterious. In short, on every crash like that I will extract the map of existing `Context` to `BroadcastReceiver` (see [ContextImpl.java:1590](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/54d9df0f041126e9d59851d76a445effd4f3590b/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L1590) and [LoadedApk.java:1361](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/54d9df0f041126e9d59851d76a445effd4f3590b/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java#L1361)).

When it unregisters normally, without a crash I can see a map like this:

```
com.mypackage.myapp.MyAppContext instance -> list of instances that are registered app wide
com.mypackage.myapp.MyActivity1 instance -> list of instances that are registered for Activity1
com.mypackage.myapp.MyActivity2 instance -> list of instances that are registered for Activity2
...
```

However, in the event of the crash this map looks like this:

```
com.mypackage.myapp.MyAppContext instance -> list of instances that are registered app wide
```

i.e. there are no activities in which my `BroadcastReceiver` is registered, even though I never called `unregisterReceiver`!

It only happens in one specific activity, so my first guess was that this activity is leaked somehow, `onDestroy` lifecycle gets called, Activity entry get removed from receivers map, and then obviously the receiver won't be there when we try to unregister it. However, if that's the case, why is `onStop` being called after `onDestroy` then? And why then the receivers list is completely empty?

And if it's not the leak, then what can lead to such puzzling behaviour? I truly hope that somebody else has experienced such a strange occurrence, and may be able to help me, because right now I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: See if any of the existing threads help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259429/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-receiver-not-registered, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542941/aused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-receiver-not-registered-null, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978167/weird-receiver-not-registered-exception

Comment: @TarunLalwani I wish it was as simple as one of these threads. Unfortunately, these are trivial cases which I've already checked first thing.

Comment: Is it happening on any specific devices or Brand?

Comment: @TarunLalwani nope, happening on different Android versions (starting with 8, at least and up to 10), and brands are wildly different - there are Samsung devices, Huawei, even Pixel ones...

Comment: Could you maybe add some code as well?

Comment: can you send your  code to my email address? maybe i can help you

Comment: @AlexanderWoodblock Did you look at my answer? Was it helpful?

Comment: This question is rather abstract. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46708690/617044 if you have not solved this already. Net-net-net: `unregisterReceiver()` is global. `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(receiver)` is what we needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Lets just say I've felt the pain. For the sake of my own problem I just found a fix, but, to answer your question I really dived deeply into docs and SO older questions even wrote simple code and checked some lifeCycle tests myself(in which I though I had found the answer which I was wrong). I couldn't find the reason this incident happens, but to fix it I suggest wrap the register/unRegister in a try catch block:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    try {
        appUpdateReceiver = new AppUpdateReceiver();
        registerReceiver(appUpdateReceiver, appUpdateIntentFilter);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // already registered
    }
}

private void unRegisterBroadCastReceiver() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(appUpdateReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // already unregistered
    }
}
```

Please provide some code so the community can look into this matter more deeply. And thanks for mentioning the LoadedApk class.

Comment: I am not certain, but are you sure your answer is not wrong? Have you ensured that there aren't two instances of Activity2 in your activity stack, and that this isn't the reason that `onStop` is seemingly not called? That would also explain why you have `Activity2: onDestroy` twice. Do you have any API references for your claim that "onStop can be called even if onStart has not."?

Comment: Even if there are 2 instances of Activity2, which I doubt, one them has not called onStart.

Comment: But you aren't showing the whole trace either, the trace starts with "Activity2: onPause (Activity2 onBackpressed)".

Comment: And if one instance of Activity2 is created, and then is immediately destroyed, it goes `onCreate` to `onDestroy`, and that fits perfectly with it not calling either `onStart` or `onStop`.

Comment: Before that there is one instance of Activity2(due to startActivity being called from Activity1) and its onStart has been called, I found it irrelevant so I didn't show all logs.

Comment: Yeah you are right I just added a hashcode to logs, those final logs are onStop and onDestroy of the first instance of Activity2. Thanks. I will modify/remove the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

> In onStart, BroadcastReceiver that is stored in the Activity field is
>   registered. In onStop, this BroadcastReceiver is unregistered.

A lot of things can happen in the `onPause` state. The app process might be killed and it might start again at `onCreate`.

Quoting from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers)

> To stop receiving broadcasts, call
>   unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver). Be sure to
>   unregister the receiver when you no longer need it or the context is
>   no longer valid.
>
> Be mindful of where you register and unregister the receiver, for
>   example, if you register a receiver in onCreate(Bundle) using the
>   activity's context, you should unregister it in onDestroy() to prevent
>   leaking the receiver out of the activity context. If you register a
>   receiver in onResume(), you should unregister it in onPause() to
>   prevent registering it multiple times (If you don't want to receive
>   broadcasts when paused, and this can cut down on unnecessary system
>   overhead). Do not unregister in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), because
>   this isn't called if the user moves back in the history stack.

So please register and unregister in `onResume` and `onPause` respectively.

Let me know if this solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you at any point read or write `isRegistered` to/from a different thread than the main application thread, for instance in a callback that is not executed by the main application thread? If so, due to possible memory consistency bugs, this may cause stale values to be read and other strange behaviour. There can be very weird behaviour if memory consistency is broken, see for instance http://jcip.net/ and http://jcip.net/listings/Holder.java . Also, do you register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the main application thread?

Have you tried checking the lifecycle in various ways to see if you could reproduce the bug yourself, such as turning the phone side-ways and causing lifecycle changes that way, or otherwise force lifecycle to change?

Do you set `isRegistered` to false after calling `unregisterReceiver`? I wonder whether this could be relevant, for instance if `onStart` is called, registration is successful, later `onStop` is called, un-registration is successful, later `onStart` is called but registration is not successful, and then `onStop` is called despite no `BroadcastReceiver` being registered due to `isRegistered` not having been reset. I don't know whether this is possible, but you describe *"When BroadcastReceiver was successfully registered"*, so I wonder if there could be an issue reg. handling of unsuccessful registration. I also wonder whether this could happen if not all branches in your `onStart` registers the broadcast receiver.

I could guess that the following link might be relevant, but you already use a variable to check whether it has been registered or not, so I would guess not: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle (though, I am uncertain whether I like or trust the wording in that text, the example it uses includes a callback).

> Moreover, there's no guarantee that the component starts before the activity or fragment is stopped. This is especially true if we need to perform a long-running operation, such as some configuration check in `onStart()`. This can cause a race condition where the `onStop()` method finishes before the `onStart()`, keeping the component alive longer than it's needed.

Comment: @AlexanderWoodblock Are any of these questions helpful? Any more information you could give?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the implementation in this way:

Releasing the receiver in the onDestroy event

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    // ...releasing more objects

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(testReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ... more initializations

    initializeBroadcastReceivers();
}


private void initializeBroadcastReceivers()
{
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
      .registerReceiver(testReceiver, 
        new IntentFilter("testReceiver"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver testReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // some code
    }
};
```